# Double list comprehension in Python - finding borders coordinates

Tags: python

Given `(x,y)`, I want the collection:

```
[(0,0),(0,y),(1,0),(1,y),(2,0),(2,y)...(x-1,0),(x-1,y),(x,0),(x,y),
             (0,1),(x,1),(0,2),(x,2)...(0,y-1),(x,y-1)]
```

(I don't really care if it is a list, set, or any other type of collection.)

I've experimented with several permutations of list comps, nothing has really worked.

I found a BAD solution::

```
all_points = list(itertools.product([x for x in range(x+1)], [y for y in range(y+1)]))
border = [xy for xy in all_points if xy[0]==0 or xy[0]==x or xy[1]==0 or xy[1]==y]
```

But I really hate this solution and am wondering if there is a more direct approach.

**EDIT**

The BAD solution can be made better, as mentioned below in comments:

```
all_points = list(itertools.product(range(x+1), range(y+1))
border = [xy for xy in all_points if xy[0]==0 or xy[0]==x or xy[1]==0 or xy[1]==y]
```

But the problem remains --- i'm just getting all the coords and then dropping the ones that aren't in the comp...

**EDIT**

The BAD solution can be made better still...

```
border = [xy for xy in itertools.product(range(x+1), range(y+1)) if xy[0]==0 or xy[0]==x or xy[1]==0 or xy[1]==y]
```

But I don't know how I feel about this...

**EDIT -- what I really want to know is...**

Is there a way to do some kind of (I dunno) recursive or loopy list comprehension that returns the desired results by directly building the list?

I can solve the practical problem of finding the coords with the bad solution. But I want to grok list comps better.

Comment: Why the `[x for x in range(x)]` instead of just `range(x)` (and I wouldn't recommend reusing names like that)?

Comment: Why not just construct the edges individually and stick them together? The comprehension to construct one edge is really simple.

Comment: Then I'm doing the same thing 4 times. I'm trying to observe DRY. I know this is a little esoteric, since I have solved the problem. But I'm trying to wrap my head around list comp. syntax.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I arrived at the above by way of trial and error from a list comp with a for loop... it made sense at the time. But what you said makes more sense.

Comment: Maybe the solution is to just improve the bad solution: `border = [xy for xy in itertools.product(range(x+1), range(y+1)) if xy[0]==0 or xy[0]==x or xy[1]==0 or xy[1]==y]`

Comment: As `x` and `y` get larger, a smaller and smaller percentage of the grid consists of border points, so any solution which involves filtering the grid is a bad idea -- it makes what should be a linear algorithm quadratic instead. Of course if `x`,`y` are small it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was a bad solution. In my specific use case, x,y are both under 2000. At 2000,2000, it takes a couple seconds on my machine. Not terrible for the task at hand, but I'd also like to know the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want a list comprehension here's one.

```
l = sorted({j for i in [[[(i, y), (i, 0)] for i in range(x+1)] + [[(x, i), (0, i)] for i in range(y+1)]][0] for j in i})
```

This will return a sorted `set` of `tuple`s.

Comment: Thanks! (And I don't even really care if it is sorted, but that does help for checking...)

Answer (score 1):

as list comprehension perhaps like this

```
def border(x,y):
    return [ (a,b) for a in range(x+1) for b in range(y+1) if 0 in (a,b) or x==a or y==b ]
```

But I rather produce directly what I need instead of searching for some esoteric and/or potentially inefficient way of doing it, is better to be clear than clever.

Like this

```
def border(x,y):
    for p in range(x+1):
        yield (p,0)
        yield (p,y)
    for p in range(1,y):
        yield (0,p)
        yield (x,p)
```

and this one is way more efficient as it don't waste time producing unnecessary stuff just to be discarded

Comment: Why not `for p in range(x+1)` and then you can skip the first four yield statements?

Comment: @rassar good catch, I try a couple of combinations, they don't work out, and those were the problematic point so I do it like that